# Why does React Hook Form returns undefined on submit?

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I write next project on typescripts. There I have form that output 4 values after form submit. But only input with controller send some value, others returns undefined:

```
{title: undefined, description: undefined, rating: 4, name: undefined} //my console log
```

My form interface:

```js
export interface IReviewForm {
    name: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    rating: number;
}
```

My form:

```
const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm<IReviewForm>();

const onSubmit = (data: IReviewForm) => {
    console.log(data);
};

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
            <Input {...register('name')} />
            <Input {...register('title')} />
            <div>
                <Controller
                    control={control}
                    name='rating'
                    render={({ field }) => (
                        <Rating isEditable rating={field.value} setRating={field.onChange} />
                    )}
                />
            </div>
            <Textarea  {...register('description')} />
            <div>
                <Button>Send</Button> //submit button
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
);
```

My package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.3.4",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
    ...
}
```

P.S.`npm i` after deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock` does not help

EDIT: It works with normal inputs. But my Input tag is also normal input without childrens:

```js
return (
    <input className={cn(className, styles.input)} {...props} />
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement your `Input` component by using `React.forwardRef` like this:

```
const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref)=> <input className={cn(className, styles.input)} {...props} ref={ref}/>)
```

consider that above implementation is just JS implementation and I dont't care about types because your problem is not realted to types.